# How to disable animation of checkbox in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

When I add checkbox and select it for one moment it gets white. How can I disable that effect. I have a grey background of frame and it dont look nice.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the default `activebackground` shade(#ececec) of a `CheckButton` in tkinter.

You can change it to match your background, while creating the `CheckButton` or later as well.

```
cb = CheckButton(root, activebackground='grey')
```

or

```
cb = CheckButton(root)
cb.config(activebackground='grey')
```

PS: Looks like you are adding extra label next to your `CheckButton` to show some text related to it, but if you need the text for your `CheckButton` then there is another attribute of `CheckButton` called `text` which can do the same job for you.

Comment: I knew that but created label because I was thinking it will help

Comment: But is there a way to disable this effect?